# R Check a row of strings, if equal, assign equal ID, less time consuming

Tags: r, performance, time, dataframe, match

im fairly new to R and was wondering if anyone here had a better solution to my problem, as mine is too time consuming. I know R is not very "for-loop-friendly" so I am sure there is a better way to solve this.

I have a data frame where x is a text string and y is a numeric id:

```
x = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a")
y = c(1,2,3,4,5)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I want a to find all matches in column x, and assign them the same numeric value as the first in y. I have solved this with the following:

```
library(foreach)
library(iterators)

for(i in 1:NROW(df)) {
  for(j in i:NROW(df)) {
    if(df$x[j] == df$x[i]){
      df$y[j] <- df$y[i]
    }
    j = j + 1
  }
  i = i + 1
}
```

Problem is, I have a fairly large dataset which makes this process take a lot of time! Hope anyone here knows a less time consuming alternative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is indeed large, then data.table will probably the fastest solution (see benchmarks [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping)).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, y := first(y), by = x]
```

Comment: This solved the problem instantly with a relatively large dataset. A consequence of this method though is that the values in y is not sequential. Anyways, it solved my problem!

Comment: You can change `key` with `keyby` which will sort x (if that is what you mean). You can also sort in place very rapidly with `setorder(df, x)`.

Comment: Woops nevermind, I entered the values in the wrong order... Haha

Answer (score 1):

R likes vectorised code, so things like arithmetic operations and assignments can be slow if done in a loop. Consider for example assigning the vector 1, 2, ... 1,000,000 to a variable `x` in two different ways

```
x <- 1:1e6
```

and

```
x <- numeric(x, 1e6) # initialise a numeric vector of length 1 million
for (i in 1:1e6) x[i] <- i
```

If you try this out you will see that the second method takes much longer.

Coming to your problem, you want to group the data by the value in `df$x` and replace the values of `y` by their first element

```
df.by <- by(df$x, function(d) transform(d, y = y[1]), data = df)
```

will set the second column of each subset of `df` (subsetting based on `df$x`) equal to its first element. The result is

```
#df$x: a
#  x y
#1 a 1
#5 a 1
#------------------------------------------------------------
#df$x: b
#  x y
#2 b 2
#4 b 2
#------------------------------------------------------------
#df$x: c
#  x y
#3 c 3
```

To combine these back to a data frame, use `df.new <- do.call(rbind, df.by)`. One (possibly unwanted) side effect of this operation is that it will change the order of the rows.

If you are new to R check out the `dplyr` package, it's got a smooth learning curve and easy to write and read syntax. What you want to do could be accomplished in only a few lines.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y = y[1])
```

will do it!